# Split string on newlines issue with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using this code to detect new lines in a string.

```
var result = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
```

However in IE8 if there are consecutive new lines only on first the string is split.

Example:

```
Hello
  ...\n
people
```

is treated like

```
Hello
people
```

appreciate any solution or advice.

Comment: So you're expecting an array with three elements, but you only get two elements? Btw, `/\r?\n/` is simpler.

Comment: didn't quite get your question?

Comment: can you show the white spaces in the example?

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: I mean all the white spaces, and put the text in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug in older versions of IE (IE8 and earlier), where `split()` drops empty elements -- exactly the problem you're reporting.

This bug is fixed in IE9, but if you need to support any IE versions older than that, then you will hit this problem.

It's really not easy to work around this bug. I've seen people suggesting [overriding the `split()` function entirely](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split), but that seems like overkill (and could have unintended side effects).

When I've had this problem in the past, I've ended up making sure that my fields always had a value, even if it was blank. For blank fields I made them into a space or a zero, or a marker character that I could then strip out later. Not sure how useful that solution would be for you in this example, but that's what I've done.

Comment: but it didn't drop the empty element in `'a||b'.split('|')`?

Comment: the bug only occurs with regex splits, not string splits, so `'|'` works, but `/|/` would fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is is a workaround to this, use `replace(separator, '\0')` first and then `split('\0')` not perfect but works.

*Example*

```
'a||b'.replace(/\|/g, '\0').split('\0'); // => ['a', '', 'b'];
```

And use this as a fix to split, seems better (not standard but simple and fix the empty element elimination issue) than the one suggested in SDC's answer. You can put it in a comment.

```
<!--[if IE lt 9]><script type="text/javascript">
(function(orgSplit) {
  String.prototype.split = function(seperator, limit) {
    if (seperator instanceof RegExp)
      return this.replace(seperator, '\0').split('\0', limit);
    else
      return orgSplit.call(this, seperator, limit);
  };
})(String.prototype.split);
</script><![endif]-->
```